# Alternatives for Numericbox in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: windows, windows-8, numeric, tile

I am trying to find a good alternative to Numericbox in a windows 8 tile application. I tried using the same numericbox that exists for windows forms but got an error saying these are not supported(?) by windows 8 applications. I noticed that the TextBox element for tile applications has a InputScope that can be set to "Number", but it still allows the user to type in whatever character he wants to. I assume the InputScope does not do what I think it does.

I am currently managing with the textbox, but because I am doing calculations the text has to constantly be converted to decimal and then back to text when I want to update the interface, in addition to having to execute several checks to make sure the user does not enter non-numeric characters. This is getting extremely tedious and being very familiar with Windows Form this seems to be a step in the wrong direction. I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: `InputScope` is used for touch input keyboard type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `NumericTextBox`, but here is a simple C#/XAML implementation that allows only digits and the decimal character.

All it does is override the `OnKeyDown` event; based on the key being pressed, it either allows or disallows the event to reach the base `TextBox` class.

I should note that this implementation is for Windows Store apps - I believe your question is about that type of app, but I am not 100% sure.

```cs
public class MyNumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleKey(e);

        if (!e.Handled)
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    bool _hasDecimal = false;
    private void HandleKey(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            // allow digits
            // TODO: keypad numeric digits here
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number1:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number2:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number3:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number4:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number5:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number6:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number7:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number8:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9:
                e.Handled = false;
                break;

            // only allow one decimal
            // TODO: handle deletion of decimal...
            case (Windows.System.VirtualKey)190:    // decimal (next to comma)
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Decimal: // decimal on key pad
                e.Handled = (_hasDecimal == true);
                _hasDecimal = true;
                break;

            // pass various control keys to base
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Delete:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back:
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab:
                e.Handled = false;
                break;

            default:
                // default is to not pass key to base
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some sample XAML. Note that it assumes `MyNumericTextBox` is in the project namespace.

```xml
<StackPanel Background="Black">
    <!-- custom numeric textbox -->
    <local:MyNumericTextBox />
    <!-- normal textbox -->
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just a note, this example doesn't cater for Shift + number, and so it allows the special characters to sneak through, also the decimal point can only be added once, if erased it can't be added again.

Answer (score 0):

The NumericUpDown control of the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) may be what you're looking for.